# Apache Click Guice integration

Tags: guice, click-framework

Is there a way of integrating apache click web framework with Google Guice such that I can use @Inject to inject Guice services into page/panel classes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the guice filter on web.xml and added the ClickServlet in guice servlet module. I then did an override on the newPageInstance() method on click servlet and called injector.injectMembers(page) to inject all the dependencies on the newly created page.

Comment: I've recently performed the same kind of stuff with Guice 3.0 but was extremely disappointed with guice-servlet (has lots of problems with forwards and URL containing jsessionid). Finally I have completely abandone guice-servlet to use only web.xml.

Comment: For your ClickServlet subclass, why don't you do `injector.getInstance(pageClass)` instead? This allows for constructor injection in your click pages.